# Bootstrap: Submit Table Data

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, submit

I try to get into bootstrap and therefore i try to build a website containing some sort of *Content-Management-interaction*. Below is a table where you can insert ingredients, which should be inserted into a MYSQL-relation. A problem arises when I fill-in the table below, because the form - which is wrapped around the table - won't submit anything.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ingredients" role="form" action="process_input.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <caption>insert ingredients</caption>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<div class="form-group">
    <td><select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select></td>
    <td> <select id="opt1b" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="3">Litre</option>
        <option value="3">Cup</option>
        <option value="4">TS</option>
  </select></td>
    <td><input id="opt1c"></td>
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</div>
</tr>

<tr>
<div class="form-group">
    <td><select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select></td>
    <td> <select id="opt1b" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="3">Litre</option>
        <option value="3">Cup</option>
        <option value="4">TS</option>
  </select></td>
    <td><input id="opt1c"></td>
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</div>
</tr>

<tr>
<div class="form-group">
    <td><select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select></td>
    <td> <select id="opt1b" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="3">Litre</option>
        <option value="3">Cup</option>
        <option value="4">TS</option>
  </select></td>
    <td><input id="opt1c"></td>
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</div>
</tr>
</tbody>
 <button class="btn btn-sucess">Send</button>
```

The *process_input.php* script is straightforward.

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Something must be wrong in the table because both arrays are still empty, after submitting.

EDIT: Thanks for all your correctings. It works now. The stackoverflow community is amazingly quick! :)

Comment: you need to take name attribute which fields you want to submit, like
`<select id="opt1a" name="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">` 
in php file now `$_POST['opt1a']`

Comment: make button as a submit button ` <button class="btn btn-sucess" type="submit">Send</button>`

Comment: and your forgot to put closing tag of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method in the code you provided is POST. 
Why use GET in PHP when you clearly submit in POST? That's one bit.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ingredients" role="form" action="process_input.php" method="POST">
```

Another thing is your submission button. You did not define the type of the button. It should be of type 'submit'.

```
<button class="btn btn-sucess" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Your **select** elements are missing the **name** attribute which PHP is using to uniquely identify the value in an input.

```
<select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="yourSelectName">
```

And finally, since you are trying to get the values via POST, please create variables that will hold the POST value of each selection box. You can follow the example below:

```
<?php
$selectBox1 = $_POST['selectBox1'];
$selectBox2 = $_POST['selectBox2'];

echo $selectBox1 . " " $selectBox2;
?>
```

Comment: Just a quick sidenote: it's not a requirement to assign the POST value of any input to a variable. You can **echo** the value of your **selectBox** simply by writing **$_POST['selectBox']**. However, its very much encouraged and it's pretty much the convention.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong in the table. Table is used to make a layout which is visible to user.

You are taking the data of form in php using the `$_GET` and `$_POST` global variable.

As I can see the input field you have not given the attribute `name` in any input.

```
<select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
```

In the above code you are missing the name attribute. So add the name attribute like this:

```
<select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="selectbox">
                                                                 ^^^name can be your choice
```

**Note:**  After form submit, PHP global variable `$_GET` or `$_POST` hold the value with the name of input field. Like above example the value will be at `$_POST['selectbox']` or `$_GET['selectbox']`

Hence you have to give the name attribute to each input type.

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue with table you need to just set inputs name attribute `name="opt1a"` like,

```
<select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="opt1a">
```

using post method you can get this select box value by that name attribute,like

```
echo $_POST['opt1a'];
```

and make your button to submit by giving type attribute,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess">Send</button>
```

and make sure your every open tag has closing tags.
without name attribute you can not get any input fields value in your server side code.
i hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After Looking into your Code Observed Few things where you are going wrong.

**1)** You Haven't Closed Form `</form>`

**2)** And You are sending all the select option values null to PHP i.e Your First option selected has no value associated with it. So finally post showing an empty array

```
<select id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
<option value="0" selected>Choose</option>
```

**3)** Give Different names for each and every select dropdown to differentiate the access.

```
<select name="differentName" id="opt1a" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
```

**4)** Form action should be the first thing after form tag opened

```
<form action="process_input.php" class="form-horizontal" id="ingredients" role="form"   method="POST">
```